# Make PHP Request to tomcat localhost using cURL and get response

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to PHP and am currently struggling to set this up. Could someone provide me an outline of how you use curl to post and retrieve the returning data?

I tried this out:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/ds/stuff?maybe=false';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I keep getting the HTTP status 405 Error
(aka this):
[image: Sadness]

Am I doing something wrong/what should I do? Or do I have to change something in my ds/stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `CURLOPT_POST` to `true`. `POST` data goes to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/ds/stuff?maybe=false';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you! :)

Side question: if I wanted to add other options like "text/text" and/or "UTF-8" would that go in $string?

Comment: @hhyder here is full list of available options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php